# Android - checking for certain value does not

Tags: java, android

I am working on Android billing and trying to set the onPurchaseStateChange method correct, but it does not seem to be working.

```
    @Override
    public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState, String itemId,
            int quantity, long purchaseTime, String developerPayload) 
    {
        if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) 
        {
            mOwnedItems.add(itemId);

            if ( itemId != null && itemId.trim().equals("3") )
            {
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(ExtraHelpActivity.this, PsychologyActivity.class);
                  ExtraHelpActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
            if ( itemId != null && itemId.trim().equals("4") )
            {
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(ExtraHelpActivity.this, NumberOfBusinessesActivity.class);
                  ExtraHelpActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);   
            }                
        }
        else 
        if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.CANCELED) 
        {  
            // purchase canceled
        } 
        else 
        if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.REFUNDED) 
        {
            // user ask for a refund
        }
        else
        {   
            if ( itemId != null && itemId.equals("3") )
            {
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(ExtraHelpActivity.this, PsychologyActivity.class);
                  ExtraHelpActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
            if ( itemId != null && itemId.equals("4") )
            {
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(ExtraHelpActivity.this, NumberOfBusinessesActivity.class);
                  ExtraHelpActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);   
            }                   
        }
```

So when the purchaseId is "4" or "3" and the purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED ....for some reason it does not seem to get into that if statement, and does not perform the intent to go to the next page?

Would anyone know why that happens? It seems very strange. Could it be a Java thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PurchaseState is not a primitive data type like `int`, `long`, `float`, etc so you should use:

```
purchaseState.equals(PurchaseState.PURCHASED)
```

instead of `==`, just like you use with Strings:

```
string1.equals(string2) // Results you expect
```

is not the same as

```
string1 == string2 // Don't do this...
```

Comment: thanks, but in my case, the purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED turned out to be true, and it seems that the next lines of code are the ones where the problem is.

Comment: Hmm, just to be certain have you verified in your debugger that `itemId` is "3" or "4" (not `purchaseId`)?

Comment: yeah..and the code was getting inside that first if statement. Its actually not from a debugger - its from a live app and I had it send me an email if it got inside that if statement, which it did, and it reported the values were as I expected them.

Comment: I confess I haven't used In-App Billing, but is ExtraHelpActivity the active Activity (in the foreground)?

Comment: good question. The ExtraHelpActivity is the current activity, BUT, the method that my code is in that we are discussing is inside an inner class.  Would that make a difference? Should I be using something like "this" or get the context another way? Thanks!